# Inequalities with floor function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How large should $n$ be in order for the following inequality to hold?

$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{m} \right\rfloor \leq 2 \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2m} \right\rfloor$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n,m > 0$ it is always the case that 
$$\left\lfloor n/m\right\rfloor \geq 2 \left\lfloor n/2m\right\rfloor 
$$
because any leftover fractional part that gets discarded is doubled on the right hand side.

We have
$$n = km+q = 2\ell m + p$$
with $0 \leq q < m$ and $p = q$ or $p=q+m$

Then $$
(k-2\ell ) m = p-q$$
so $k > 2\ell$ if $k$ is odd.

Therefore, $$\left\lfloor n/m\right\rfloor \leq 2 \left\lfloor n/2m\right\rfloor 
$$ only if $\left\lfloor n/m\right\rfloor$ is even.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why p=q or p=q+m?

Comment: Because $p-q = (2\ell - k)m$ so $p-q$ is divisible by $m$ but must be less than $2m$ since $p < 2m$.

Comment: Then the relation will always hold if $n > 2m^2 - 3m$. It will never hold for $n = 2m^2 - 3m$ but it will also hold for $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ values of $n$ between $m$ and $2m^2 - 3m$. These are grouped in runs of $n-1, n-2, \ldots 2,1$.